# Yii Website shows old pages

Tags: caching, yii, history

I am not sure why, but lately, my yii 1 website shows pages from the cache too much. Earlier, if I uploaded via FTP, it'd show the latest page. Now it doesn't do that. I also get complaints from users that they are now faced with old pages or they have problems that are later fixed with a history clear.

What could potential problems be. Can I tune down Yii caching or flush it?

Comment: Yii doesn't cache whole pages. But it's possible via headers from scrips or server settings.

Comment: Actually, I am just updating a website created by another developer and it is a mess. Can you suggest where can I start looking for things I need to change.

Comment: httpd.conf, vhosts.conf, .htaccess, `header()`